# Ports of a private IP?

Tags: c#, networking, ip

I apologize if this a duplicate, but I have not been able to understand most of the answers that seem similar. It's hard to navigate all of the wikipedia pages and stuff without knowledge of them already.

I know that a router with a public IP address can use the port of incoming requests to determine which private device it should send it to. But the problem is that every private IP address also has ports, so how does the router decide not only which IP address to send a packet to, but also which port of that private IP address it should be on?

The only way I can think of right now is that port mapping maps every incoming port to both the IP and the port, for example port `11000` could go to `192.168.86.250:25565`. The more I write this the more it seems obvious, but can someone please confirm this is how it works?

Also, bonus points if someone could point me in the right direction for using c# to determine a port that could be used with my public IP to get to my program which is running on `192.168.86.250:25565`.

Comment: "so how does the router decide not only which IP address to send a packet to, but also which port of that private IP address it should be on?" - the same way it decides which IP to send it to... the information is stored in memory... isn't this the logical, most straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Yeah, I was under the belief that it was some sort of algorithm instead of stored in memory. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Looks like you wanted to know about [UPnP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play).

Comment: You can set up port forwarding on your router which is more secure than using UPnP. One should understand the security risks of having UPnP enabled: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38631/what-are-the-security-implications-of-enabling-upnp-in-my-home-router

Comment: Application register for ports (in c# with +-).  Windows then send incoming messages to the application that registers for the port.  The IP address and port number are in the IP Packet Header.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4

Answer (score 0):

> I know that a router with a public IP address can use the port of incoming requests to determine which private device it should send it to.

That's called *port forwarding*, *destination NAT*, or *reverse NAT*.

> But the problem is that every private IP address also has ports, so how does the router decide not only which IP address to send a packet to, but also which port of that private IP address it should be on?

The (NAT) router forwards a public *IP:port* combination to a private *IP:port* combination for either TCP or UDP. You can't forward to an IP address alone.

For the port numbers to use, you should take a look at the *well-known port list*: https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml